# Limit access to specific records in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My application consists of Facilities, each of which have many Patients, who each have many Contacts.

Each facility should have 1 user, who should be the only person who can view/edit/add/delete their facility as well as any patients/contacts/etc. within that facility.

What I'm trying to avoid is checking every time for each patient/contact/etc. whether it matches the current user_id before I can view/edit/add/delete. (Something like this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/RKa5NhqVEjQ)

I've set up ACL and Auth hoping that I could accomplish this but haven't had any luck restricting each user to only their facility using ACL and/or Auth.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid repeating code, or are you trying to limit database accesses?  If you're just want to avoid repeating code, I can think of several ways to approach it.  There's an article on limiting access by writing a new find function, http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/harisenbon/2010/08/23/how-to-limit-user-access-in-cakephp-findmy, you could also possibly write a custom find type, or possibly even replacing the default find behavior with one that will check for the proper user_id, or add something to beforeFilter or isAuthorized to prevent user access.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ACL then you can use a callback.
For example, in you Model or AppModel you can have a afterFind function that checks if the patients belongs to certain facility. You would need to write this logic only once.